# Grouping lines into heterogeneous subsets

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk, perl

I have file with *n* lines.  (Each line refers to a “question”, and
therefore they are labeled `Q.1`, `Q.2`, `Q.3`, ..., `Q.n`.) 
Each line (question) has a “Marks” attribute,
which has the value 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6. 
There are <sup>*n*</sup>⁄<sub>5</sub> lines with each value.

For example: A 10-line file (i.e., *n*=10) might look like

```
amol@mypc:~$ cat questions.txt
Q.1 2 Marks
Q.2 5 Marks
Q.3 4 Marks
Q.4 3 Marks
Q.5 6 Marks
Q.6 4 Marks
Q.7 3 Marks
Q.8 2 Marks
Q.9 6 Marks
Q.10 5 Marks
```

I know I can split this into five *homogeneous* (i.e., all the same) files
with something like

```
amol@mypc:~$ grep " 2 Marks" questions.txt > questions2Marks.txt
amol@mypc:~$ grep " 3 Marks" questions.txt > questions3Marks.txt
amol@mypc:~$ grep " 4 Marks" questions.txt > questions4Marks.txt
amol@mypc:~$ grep " 5 Marks" questions.txt > questions5Marks.txt
amol@mypc:~$ grep " 6 Marks" questions.txt > questions6Marks.txt
```

Each of the resulting files will have <sup>*n*</sup>⁄<sub>5</sub> lines.

I want to do the inverse operation –
i.e., produce a transpose of the above result. 
I want to split my `questions.txt` file
into <sup>*n*</sup>⁄<sub>5</sub> files: `questions1.txt`,
`questions2.txt`, `questions3.txt`, ..., `questionsM.txt`
(using *M* to represent <sup>*n*</sup>⁄<sub>5</sub>) where each file
is five lines long and is *heterogeneous* (i.e., all different).

`questions1.txt` should contain

- the first line in `questions.txt` with `2 Marks`,
- the first line in `questions.txt` with `3 Marks`,
- the first line in `questions.txt` with `4 Marks`,
- the first line in `questions.txt` with `5 Marks`, and
- the first line in `questions.txt` with `6 Marks`,

in that order.  `questions2.txt` should contain the second line of each, etc.

So, for *n*=10, *M* obviously is 2.  I would want my example `questions.txt` from above broken down into these two files:

```
amol@mypc:~$ cat questions1.txt            
Q.1 2 Marks
Q.4 3 Marks
Q.3 4 Marks
Q.2 5 Marks
Q.5 6 Marks

amol@mypc:~$ cat questions2.txt            
Q.8 2 Marks
Q.7 3 Marks
Q.6 4 Marks
Q.10 5 Marks
Q.9 6 Marks
```

How can I achieve that using *nix tools
(sed, awk, perl, shell script, etc...)?

Comment: So you want to read the file sequentially, and each time you get a group of values 2-3-4-5-6 from the second column, sort the group on that column, and write it to a numbered file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sort -n -k2 -k1.3 file | awk '{$2!=a?x=1:x++} {print > "file"x; a=$2}'
```

First , we need to sort the file correctly. `-n` sorts the file numerically, `-k2` sorts according to the second field (the marks 2-6), `-k1.3` then sorts within this order the first field starting from the 3rd character numerically (irgnoring the leading `Q.`). Now `awk` splits the output between ascending files (file1, file2, file3, filen....).

The output looks like this, `file1`:

```
$ cat file1
Q.1 2 Marks
Q.4 3 Marks
Q.3 4 Marks
Q.2 5 Marks
Q.5 6 Marks
```

And `file2`:

```
$ cat file2
Q.8 2 Marks
Q.7 3 Marks
Q.6 4 Marks
Q.10 5 Marks
Q.9 6 Marks
```

Comment: Could also do `awk '{print > "file"!(NR%2)+1}'`

Comment: @chaos : You are quite correct. But I have file with lots of questions say 100 questions in a file of 2,3,4,5 and 6 Marks. How can I divide them into file1, file2, file3..............upto file20 for 100 questions. So that it will create 20 files of each 2,3,4,5 and 6 Marks..Hope you understand my query....

Comment: @amolveer I edited my answer, now it's working with multiple files.

Comment: @chaos : Perfect, cool man

Answer (score 3):

an awk answer: this will keep the order the questions the same as in the source file.

```
$ awk '{filename = "questions" ++n[$2] ".txt"; print > filename}' questions.txt 
$ cat questions1.txt 
Q.1 2 Marks
Q.2 5 Marks
Q.3 4 Marks
Q.4 3 Marks
Q.5 6 Marks
$ cat questions2.txt 
Q.6 4 Marks
Q.7 3 Marks
Q.8 2 Marks
Q.9 6 Marks
Q.10 5 Marks
```